# Unplugged old bad disk, ran update-grub, but old menu options (on unplugged disk) still appear

Tags: grub2, disk

so this must be a common problem.  I had an old Windows machine with a disk that started to go bad (just some bad spots, corrupted files).  So, I installed a new disk beside the old one and put Mint 17 on it.  grub-mkconfig picked everything up.  Life was good.

Then one day, the old windows disk fully died, click, click.  So, I unplugged both power and data cables from it, ran update-grub.  HOWEVER... I'm still seeing old stuff from the unplugged partition in my grub boot menu (Dell partition recovery, etc.).  So, obviously, I've left a step or two out.  What?

Comment: did you try running `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: I did. As noted in the OP.